# jquery jqmodal .load() issue

Tags: safari, load, jqmodal

I have a modal window using jqmodal. I need a button within that modal to load a different page in the modal. I have this functioning in all browsers except safari.

JS

```
<script language="javascript">
function shipCalc() {
$('.jqmWindow').load("/ash/shop/shipping.php");
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<form name="form9" id="form9" method="post">
Zip: <input type="text" size="5" name="zip">
<a href="#" id="submitbtn" onclick= "shipCalc();" >zip</a>
</form>
```

KEEP IN MIND! The class .jqmWindow is a modal window using the jqmodal jquery plugin. It is NOT just a div on a page. I am using the method .load() to change what has been loaded in the modal window after it has popped up. The html shown above is inside the page that is originally loaded in the modal. I am having trouble understanding why this works in all browsers besides safari. I posted earlier and got some responses that weren't quite addressing the real problem here, which is that I can not use the .load() method to load anything into my modal window in safari. (Ive stripped some non-important information regarding future modifications I will make to further make this suite the needs of the site, just to keep this nice and simple to understand...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function shipCalc() needed to be on both the initial page AND the page that gets loaded into the modal for safari to load everything properly. All other browsers did not require that. All is working now, so I figured I would post my own answer in case anyone was ever searching for something similar!